# JSON.stringify in java - android

Tags: java, android, json, stringify

Is there any way to perform a `JSON.stringify` in android?

I keep seeing `JSON.stringify(JSONObject)` all around the web, but I cant find the JSON class in android.

Any help?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`JSON.stringify(JSONObject)` is a Javascript function and will not be available in Java. If you're using the `org.json.*` package built in the Android SDK, the equivalent would be to simply call `toString()` on your `JSONObject` instance, or the more human-friendly `toString(int)`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString()
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString(int)

```
JSONObject obj = ...
String jsonString = obj.toString(4);
```

Answer (score 16):

I know this is old, but I ran into the same problem. And there doesn't seem to be much about it here... so I thought I would add what I learned.

I used a third-party library to aid in the endeavor: `org.codehaus.jackson`
All of the downloads for this can be found [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson).

For base JSON functionality, you need to add the following jars to your project's libraries:
[jackson-mapper-asl](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl)
and
[jackson-core-asl](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl)

Choose the version your project needs. (Typically you can go with the latest stable build).

Once they are imported in to your project's libraries, add the following `import` lines to your code:

```
 import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
 import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
 import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
```

With the java object defined and assigned values that you wish to convert to JSON and return as part of a RESTful web service

```
User u = new User();
 u.firstName = "Sample";
 u.lastName = "User";
 u.email = "sampleU@example.com";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
try {
    // convert user object to json string and return it 
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(u);
}

  // catch various errors
  catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
  catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The result should looks like this:
`{"firstName":"Sample","lastName":"User","email":"sampleU@example.com"}`

Answer (score 1):

Basic actions with JSON objects in JAVA can be done either with a help of `org.json` package (included in Android SDK) or `javax.json` (part of JAVA EE). Both of them have `toString()` method for conversion of JSONObject to string:

```
//assuming you have object `jsonobject` of class `JSONObject`
String output = jsonobject.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple to import **com.google.gson.Gson**, code sample: `String json =  new Gson().toJson(yourObject);`