# Is there a way to create the exact same String of a Java <-> JSON mapped object like the JSON.stringify(jsObject) creates?

Tags: javascript, java, json, string

my problem is that i need the exact same String for hashing them later on. The first String comes from the javascript object with JSON.stringify, and the second one is a java object, mapped from the JSON. 
I need a method to "use" the stringify method on my java object.
All quotes, spaces...need to be exact same because I need the same hashvalue to compare them later on. If someone here has a wink or the same problem, i'll be happy if you share it!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at GSON

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077955/json-stringify-in-java-android

Answer (score 0):

i can offer a couple of suggestions if that helps

1. if you have control over both js and java versions, then normalise the object before json-encoding it (either in both or at least one of them)
2. try to use a java JSON lib that closely emulates the js version (or vice-versa), eg [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)
3. write your json-encoder (either in java,js or both), its not that hard

Comment: thx man, I'll have a look at GSON, but I think that the normalization could be the way!